# Cisco ASA firewall blocking requests to internally hosted DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, nat, tcp, cisco-asa, dns-hosting

I have a DNS server behind a Cisco ASA firewall. The Cisco firewall is performing NAT. When inside the network, I can NSLOOKUP directly to the server. When the client is external, requests time out.

Assuming the internal IP Address of the DNS Server is 10.0.0.10 and the public IP Address is 1.2.3.4:

My relevant configs:

```
object network NS1_SERVVE_COM_dns
 host 10.0.0.10

access-list outside_in extended permit tcp any object NS1_SERVVE_COM_dns eq domain 

object network NS1_SERVVE_COM_dns
 nat (inside,outside) static 1.2.3.4 service tcp domain domain
```

Also I entered the following to allow Active Directory to resolve internet names:

```
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 8192
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map
```

I have tried to change TCP to UDP, but the result is the same. Any thoughts?

firewall# packet-tracer input outside tcp 4.2.2.1 domain 1.2.3.4 domai$

```
Phase: 1
Type: UN-NAT
Subtype: static
Result: ALLOW
Config:
object network NS1_SERVVE_COM_dns
 nat (inside,outside) static 1.2.3.4 service tcp domain domain 
Additional Information:
NAT divert to egress interface inside
Untranslate 1.2.3.4/53 to 10.0.0.10/53

Phase: 2
Type: ACCESS-LIST
Subtype: log
Result: ALLOW
Config:
access-group outside_in in interface outside
access-list outside_in extended permit tcp any object NS1_SERVVE_COM_dns eq domain 
Additional Information:

Phase: 3
Type: NAT
Subtype: per-session
Result: ALLOW
Config:       
Additional Information:

Phase: 4
Type: IP-OPTIONS
Subtype: 
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:

Phase: 5
Type: NAT
Subtype: rpf-check
Result: ALLOW
Config:
object network NS1_SERVVE_COM_dns
 nat (inside,outside) static 1.2.3.4 service tcp domain domain 
Additional Information:

Phase: 6
Type: NAT
Subtype: per-session
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:

Phase: 7
Type: IP-OPTIONS
Subtype: 
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:

Phase: 8
Type: FLOW-CREATION
Subtype: 
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:
New flow created with id 7845414, packet dispatched to next module

Result:
input-interface: outside
input-status: up
input-line-status: up
output-interface: inside
output-status: up
output-line-status: up
Action: allow
```

Comment: `I have tried to change TCP to UDP` - did you change it both for the NAT rule and for the ACL?  What's `packet-tracer` say when you simulate a DNS packet to the system from outside?

Comment: Shane, I changed both the ACL (actually now both rules are still i there), as well as the NAT statement. I did not run a packet tracer.... I'm just getting used to the ASAs, and have not pulled up ADSM. Not sure how to run the packet tracer, but I will google it and find the result.

Comment: Shane, packet tracer added.

Comment: That's TCP, you really should be testing UDP as it's the vast majority of DNS traffic.  Verify that the results for UDP are the same?

Comment: Looks like when I changed all TCP to UDP, its working now, I must have forgotten to change the NAT statement from TCP to UDP the last time, but now i have external queries working! Thanks for your help Shane!